# Is the html 'step' attributte not working anymore?

Tags: html, angularjs

So I'm working in this Angularjs project using mostly material. I need to setup a timepicker so I'm using the input control with the type=time. Problem is, I need to setup this control to only let the user pick the time in a 30 minutes range. For example, 11:30 or 11:00 are allowed times; 11:12 is not.

If I remember correctly, one can use the "step" attribute to skip the minutes as needed but it seems it is not working anymore. For example, I setup the step attribute to 3600 but I'm still able to pick any minut in the clock.

[image]
[image]

How can I fix this?

Here is the part of the input code:

```
<md-input-container style="margin-top: 20px; min-width: 98%; margin-bottom:0;">
    <label class="label-form-empleados" style="">
        Hora Inicio Cita:
    </label>
    <input ng-model="HoraInicio" ng-disabled="fDisableHoraInicio" data-ng-change="CalcularHoraFin(ServicioSeleccionado)" type="time" step="3600" class="" placeholder="Hora inicio cita ..." autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" id="timeInicio" tabindex="11">
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: Please show your full relevant HTML code not just screenshots of part of your code.

Comment: Please post the full element as code, rather than posting a portion of the element as a screenshot. If possible a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Please also [**Ensure you have read the full details**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Using_the_step_attribute) about this input element

Answer (score 0):

With an input of 1800 the step will be 30minutes. This should work.

```
<input type="time" id="appt" name="appt"
       min="09:00" max="18:00" step="1800" required>
```

Another option is use [Kendo UI](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datetimepicker/incremental-steps/) api for Angular. You'll only need to set the attributes.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it. BTW, I tried your code but I can still select all the minutes. Is it supposed to be like that? Would you be so kind to provide me a screenshot of how it display on your side? Maybe I'm trying to do something that is not possible. I just want to show :00 and: 30 in the minut picker.